# How to make a sum by element in a array?

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to make a sum of a range based on two conditions. I want a sum by element of my array and to put the value by element in a different cell. Something like:

> Range("A1") = sum of 867000
>
> Range("A2") = sum of 868000.

Hope I'm clear.

I've tried several `For Each` constructs but this is the closest I came from what I wish.

```
 Dim cel1 As Range

 Dim rng As Range

 Dim rngDataCSF As Range
 Set rngDataCSF = Sheets("data").Range("D2400:D" & Sheets("data").Range("B5").Value + 6)

 Dim arr889 As Variant
 Dim element As Variant
 arr889 = Array("867000", "868000")

 For Each element In arr889
   For Each cel1 In rngDataCSF

    If cel1.Value = element Then
        If Sheets("data").Cells(cel1.Row, 1) = "889" And _
           Sheets("data").Cells(cel1.Row, 4) = element Then

           Sheets("t").Range("A1").Value = Sheets("t").Range("A1").Value + _
                      Sheets("data").Cells(cel1.Row, 19).Value 'sum of 867000
           'Sheets("t").Range("A2").Value = Sheets("t").Range("A2").Value + _
                     'Sheets("data").Cells(cel1.Row, 19).Value ' sum of 868000
        End If
    End If
  Next cel1
Next element
```

Comment: What do you mean "sum of 86700", do you just mean that value? You can access the various parts of the array with `arr889(0)` and `arr889(1)` to get `867000` and `868000` respectively.

Comment: why not just use `SUMIF()`?

Comment: In my exemple there's is only 2 elements in my array but there's a lot more. I want the sum of the value in the colomn 19 if the value is = 867000. Same with 868000.

Comment: So put the array element is a column Say A2:A?? then in B2 put `=SUMIFS(data!S:S,data!A:A,889,data!D:D,A2)` and copy down.

Comment: @MaxBridge if you have the elements as a list in excel, you can use Scott's suggestion of sumifs directly next to said list, using the list as references in the sumifs formula

Comment: @ScottCraner Ok It works!  My Excel  is in french so different I had to use another formula. I still would appreciate to know it in vba. But Thanks to all of you have a nice Weekend

Comment: If you really want to work on your VBA you need to, at the very least, describe how what you have is not working. Even better would be a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the test environment... Just keep it simple :-)

Answer (score 0):

to extend scrott's solution:
imho, to use cell references as criteria list, you need to enter them with ctrl+shift+enter

`=SUMM(SUMIFS(data!S:S,data!A:A,889,data!D:D,A:A))`
so it becomes
`={SUM(SUMIFS(data!S:S,data!A:A,889,data!D:D,A:A))}`